# Whether apple review board accept to adjust the volume and brightness control or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appstore-approval

We are using AVPlayer in video player application, We need to adjust screen brightness by swiping up and down on the left side of the screen and adjust screen Volume by swiping up and down on the right side of the screen. We have implemented using below code

Brightness adjustment

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:brightness];
```

Volume adjustment

```
volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];  
    [self.view addSubview:volumeView];  
    for (id view in volumeView.subviews)  
    {  
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]])  
        {  
            volumeSlider = (UISlider*)view;  
            NSLog(@"volumeSlider %f",volumeSlider.value);  
        }  
    }
```

Now we need to know about whether Apple review board accept this feature or not?

Comment: This topic should be closed.  Simply, nobody has the answer.  Additionally, the app doesn't sound like it has even been rejected.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not face any difficulties for approval of your app because ::

1) You are adjusting screen brightness manually(Letting users do that) and that's quite normal and some of the apps do that already.

2) You let users adjust volume with `swipe gesture` which is also normal and is not against any of apple's review guidelines.

You can find more about review guidelines https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84232